# How to know which variable has a value and which one is null?

Tags: php, validation, email, phone-number

I need to validate an input which I will need to later check against a database for its presence in the table. The input either has to be a mobile number (all digits, 10 max len) or an email address. This below is what I did

```
<?php

$credential = '9999999999';

if (ctype_digit($credential)) {
        $mobile_number = $credential;
        echo 'Mobile: '. $mobile_number;
    } elseif (filter_var($credential, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email = $credential;
        echo 'Email: '.$email;
    }
```

**output** when `$credential = '9999999999'`;

```
Mobile: 9999999999
```

**output** when `$credential = 'abc@gmail.com'`;

```
Email: abc@gmail.com
```

Two questions,

1. Is there a better way of doing it? Like, using preg_match.
2. The above code manages to differentiate between an email and a mobile number which later I need to match against a database. In a real scenario, the input will be user-supplied, `$credential = $_POST['credential'];` and then either of two variable will be set accordingly. How do I know which of the two variable is set? If I am to match email to email column or mobile number to the mobile column, I need to know which of the two has value and which one is null.

Comment: What are you doing if neither of the conditions return true?  ...okay, you've gone away, me too.

Comment: @mickmackusa, hey thank you for the reply and sorry, had to go. This isn't the exact code but an idea I wanted to present, the validation too isn't up to the mark for production, the idea is to have a 10-digit mobile number (no whitespace in between, trimmed on both ends) or a valid email. If there is a match good else echo no record found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter_var($credential, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` is going to perform better than regex, because that is what it is specifically designed to do.

As for the phone numbers, this seems a little undercooked or too strict.  Many people add spaces, parentheses, hyphens, etc without much thought.  It will only be irritating to be so strict on the phone number, I think.  There are plenty of regex patterns on SO regarding phone number validation.  Intimate knowledge of your expected phone number strings are required to answer this confidently.  Are you expecting US numbers only?  is this international?  We don't know, so I can't say what is the best strategy.

This will work:

```
if (ctype_digit($credential) && strlen($credential)==10) {
    $mobile_number = $credential;
    echo 'Mobile: '. $mobile_number;
} elseif (filter_var($credential, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = $credential;
    echo 'Email: '.$email;
}
```

This will also work:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$credential)) {
    $mobile_number = $credential;
    echo 'Mobile: '. $mobile_number;
} elseif (filter_var($credential, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = $credential;
    echo 'Email: '.$email;
}
```

The speed differences between the two methods will be totally unnoticeable to your users.  You should choose whichever approach you prefer personally.

Comment: the second question? How does the code know which $variable has a value? Say, if email supplied, I would want to check it against the email column, or if mobile no. supplied, match it to the mobile column in the table/database.

Comment: You can either construct your query in this `if`/`elseif` block or later in your script you can write `if (!$email){...`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for answering my first question. For the second part, if you interested, I found this http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php (untested).

Comment: for question 2: consider using `isset($xxx)` or `empty($xxx)`.  `is_null($xxx)` will trigger a E_NOTICE error log if the variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it with PHP

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $string) || filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //valid
} else {
    //invalid
}
```

however, you should validate this on client-side as well, to make sure a request is not even sent to the server if the value is invalid.

EDIT:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $string)) {
    //valid mobile
} else if (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //valid email
} else {
    //invalid
}
```

Comment: I will on the client side as well ... my second question?

Comment: @Mecom in the if you have a mobile number and in the else if you have an email.